# VBO is not 'seeing' hook_flag_validate

Tags: 7, flags, views

I have used [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) on a view for a particular set of nodes that have a flag associated with them. In the view I have included a javascript toggle button for each node so a user can flag the nodes they want one at a time. When clicked, this button runs a custom PHP script to do some external stuff. I have then implemented `hook_flag_validate` so that if this external stuff fails for any reason, the node isn't flagged and an error message is displayed to the user.

This all works fine when clicking an individual toggle button, but the problem occurs when I try to flag the nodes with VBO. The nodes are still flagged or not flagged depending on the success of the PHP script, but the message displayed to the user by VBO is always a success message.

I would like to find a way to allow VBO to 'see' which flagging have failed or not (so to see the return value of hook_flag_validate for each node) and then to display a custom message describing which flagging have failed and which have succeeded.

I am using Drupal 7.41.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible - VBO doesn't handle failed operations as such, it unconditionally considers success to be `TRUE` if the batch it's processing gets to the end (i.e. doesn't throw an exception). It doesn't have any hooks to allow you to run a function when it's completed either, nor give you the opportunity to affect the batch it sets up, so you couldn't even write a custom action which logged the errors in the session and picked them up at the end. Tricky one

Comment: I solved this by simply calling drupal_set_message in hook_flag_validate whenever there is an error. This doesn't work with the ajax button toggle type, but with the confirmation screen type it works well with VBO and when flagging single rows. VBO still isn't really reacting to anything but users can't tell so it's still fine